# Take comma separated multiple integer values as input using argparse and check if any of those values are present in a list

Tags: python, list, arguments, tuples, argparse

I have a list, for example:

```
L1 = [["Apple" , 1 ,  200] , ["Grapes" , 4 , 100] , ["Banana" , 1 , 20]]
```

Using argparse, I want user to input comma separated multiple integer values.

If the value of the user's input exists in the list at the middle position i.e. at `L1[1]`, that entire list should be printed.

For example:

```
python test.py -x 1,2
```

Should output:

```
Apple , 1, 200
Banana , 1 , 20
```

I tried storing user input as a tuple.

How can I compare those tuple elements with middle position of my lists ?

How can I implement this ?

How should I store user input and check every element of user's input with my list ?

Thanks for any help in advance !

Comment: What is your question about this? Was there a particular problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: What is your actual question?  "How do I accept a comma-separated list of integers wirth argparse?"

Comment: How should I store user input and check every element of user's input with my list ?

Comment: I tried storing user input as a tuple. How can I compare those tuple elements with middle position of my lists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the user input integers in a tuple, you can do this:

```
user_input = (1, 2)
L1 = [["Apple", 1, 200], ["Grapes", 4, 100], ["Banana", 1, 20]]

for i in user_input:
    for sublist in L1:
        if i == sublist[1]:
            print(sublist)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! Much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: import argparse
```

Define a parser:

```
In [6]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()    
In [7]: parser.add_argument('-x', nargs='+', type=int);
```

test an input.  By using `nargs` and `type`, I input a space separated numbers, and get back a list of numbers:

```
In [8]: args = parser.parse_args('-x 1 2'.split())

In [9]: args
Out[9]: Namespace(x=[1, 2])
```

Then its easy to find elements of `L1` with a list comprehension (or loop if you prefer):

```
In [10]: L1 = [["Apple" , 1 ,  200] , ["Grapes" , 4 , 100] , ["Banana" , 1 , 20]]

In [11]: [val for val in L1 if val[1] in args.x]
Out[11]: [['Apple', 1, 200], ['Banana', 1, 20]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! Much appreciated !